# Create network between physical machine and ubuntu vm running docker hosting a “Stack“ of containers, with two web applications, an Nginx proxy

Tags: linux, networking, router, proxy, port-forwarding

I have to configure a WM with ubutu in the virtual box that will be the server, it will run a container with two web applications and an nginx proxy, accessed directly from the Windows environment, all instantiated via docker compose, the two applications will run on port 9000 and 9001.

The NGINX server must run on port 80, redirecting client requests to application ports in the “/app01/status” and “/app02/status” routes.

My problem arises in the following way, I am not able to create access to the application on the windows client machine, I cannot find a way to access the application by name, I can only use IP 192.168.1.2:9000 and 192.168.1.2:9001 I would like to do domain name access:
http://server-linux/app01/ and http://server-linux/app02/.

below what the topology will look like:

So far so good I can create all docker-compose with the configuration and make the application run in the virtual machine on the respective ports in my case 192.168.1.2:9000 and 192.168.1.2:9001 more on windows only accessed by ip and port.

I would like a light to raise this access and make it possible for the browser of the windows machine to load both applications with domain http://server-linux then bring the application directory when putting /app01 load app 01 and when /app02 load app 02

my docker-compose was like this (I added in addition to the two applications a database in postgres on port 5432)

```
version: '3'

services:

    app01:

       build: ./app01/.

        command: uvicorn main:app --host app01 --port 80
        ports:
            - 9000:80            
        networks:
            - webnotes_network
    app02:
        build:./app02/.
        env_file:
            - app02.env
        command: uvicorn API_Server:app --host app02 --port 80
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 9001:80            
        networks:
            - webnotes_network
db:

   image:"postgres:13-alpine"
    
 restart: always

        env_file:
            - db.env
        volumes:
            - ./db_data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        ports:      
            - '5432:80'
        networks:
            - webnotes_network
    server:
        build: ./server/.
        volumes:
            - ./server/html_files/:/usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:      
            - '9004:80'
        depends_on:
            - db
            - app02
        networks:
            - webnotes_network


networks:
    webnotes_network:
       driver: bridge
```

Comment: It sounds as though you're asking assistance doing your homework.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find a way to access the application by name.

Names such as `server-linux` require the machine in question to know that the name `server-linux` points to the IP `192.168.1.2`.

If only the host machine needs to know this name, then on Windows the easiest way to accomplish this is to edit the Windows `hosts` file.

Otherwise, if devices on your network other than the host machine need to map `server-linux` to `192.168.1.2`, then you should set up a local DNS server such as BIND. BIND had native Windows software in the past, but has apparently moved on to only supporting Linux in its most current versions. However, they do have an [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/internetsystemsconsortium/bind9) you may be interested in.

Note that using BIND locally in the manner described will likely require that your router use your local DNS server for all DNS resolution, including "normal" internet browsing. BIND can be configured to resolve local names (`server-linux`) and pass unknown names (`google.com`) upstream to your regular ISP DNS servers or whatever you typically use.

> The NGINX server must run on port 80, redirecting client requests to application ports in the `/app01/status` and `/app02/status` routes.

This is known as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). You need to point all incoming HTTP requests (port 80 on the host) at NGINX. You will likely need one server block for `http://server-linux` configured with two paths (`/app01` and `/app02`) that each redirect to your correct IP and port combinations. Be aware that forwarding requests like this may require some extra configuration in NGINX to pass all the necessary data along to your apps to allow them to work correctly. Also, `/app01` and `/app02` assume that `status` is a page generated by the Docker apps themselves.

Comment: thanks for the reply, you managed to solve my problem.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad you got things working. =)